# Embedded audio in swf not playing in another swf

Tags: flash

Developing a flash animation, it's quite long so i decided to make it modular.

I have these single flash movies which have sound and graphics, then i export each one as a .swf file.

Now i have a master flv which I want to make as a collection of child flash files.

So i imported individual swf to stage, such that they start and end in sequence.

The issue is the master flv, when i compile and play does not play the sound from the child flv. The sound is embedded in the child flv but do not play in the master.

Is there something I am missing or what is the correct way to embed a swf within an swf?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "a master flv", but did you know that FLV is a video format ? Could you explain more the problem ? some code, snapshots, anything ...

Comment: ok, sorry, a bit rusty on flash, i meant a master fla file i.e. a flash animation that acts as container for all the children fla or swf

Comment: In that case, could you give us more details about how did you play your different SWFs inside the main one ? And how did you play that sound inside the child SWF ? Also, why not just using scenes ? ...

Comment: Sure.. I created the child swf and complied them and played them in the SWF player for testing purposes. Then opened the master fla and imported each child swf to library and added them to layer and finally to stage. Now when i try to run the master fla the child swf sound does not play, but the animation plays.